# Plone and deco.gs

Tags: plone

I am trying to use plone 4 with deco, using this buildout: http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/plone.app.deco/buildouts/dev/

It seems to work, but when I add the new page element nothing special happens. (No deco.gs)

Anyone knows what is happening? or know a way of making it work with plone 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deco is still experimental as of this writing, and shouldn't be used in production just yet.

Steps to get it working (what's currently working, that is) can be found in the install docs:

http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/plone.app.deco/trunk/docs/INSTALL.txt

Answer (score 1):

As far as i am aware, there has recently been a refactoring leaving the Deco UI editor not in a workable state. It shouldn't be a lot of work to repair, but it would be best if one of the core developers would do it. 
Your best bet is probably asking on the plone.dev list to make someone do a small development push.